# Select Start Date-End Date with VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have some trouble with my codes. I want to select start day and end the day with VBA button.

This is my code. Somebody can help me? thanks a lot...

(sorry for my bad English).

**My Code:**

```
Sub CARI()
Dim objname As String
Dim jumpv As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim S1 As Date
Dim S2 As Date

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
objname = Cells(5, 5).Value
S1 = Cells(6, 4).Value
S2 = Cells(6, 9).Value
jumpv = 4

 Worksheets("PV").Activate
For I = 4 To jumpv
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading.. ( " & Round(I / jumpv * 100, 0) & ")%"

        Sheets("PV").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").CurrentPage = objname
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=S1, Value2:=S2
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").AutoSort _
        xlAscending, "DAY"
Next I
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Application.StatusBar = ""
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

[image: capture PV table]

Comment: "I have some trouble with my codes" > what is the problem? is there any specific error that you've got?

Comment: Error "Unable to get pivottables property of the worksheet class."

.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").ClearAllFilters

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code as comments :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CARI()

Dim objname As String
Dim jumpv As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim S1 As Date
Dim S2 As Date

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Dashboard") ' <-- use With instead of Activate or Select the sheet
    objname = .Cells(5, 5).Value
    S1 = .Cells(6, 4).Value
    S2 = .Cells(6, 9).Value
End With

jumpv = 4

With Worksheets("PV")
    For I = 4 To jumpv
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading.. ( " & Round(I / jumpv * 100, 0) & ")%"

        .PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").ClearAllFilters
        .PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").CurrentPage = objname
        .PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").ClearAllFilters

        ' when filtering dates, safest way is to covert to Double (their actual value, not their format)
        .PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").PivotFilters.Add _
                Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CDbl(S1), Value2:=CDbl(S2)
        .PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("DAY").AutoSort xlAscending, "DAY"
    Next I
End With

Sheets("Dashboard").Select

Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still debug on this conde
.PivotTables("PV" & I).PivotFields("REGION").ClearAllFilters

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin are you sure you have a `PivotField` named "REGION" ? verify your spelling (or extra spaces)

Comment: yes i have, PivotField named "REGION" already on Worksheets "PV".

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin what is the name of your `PivotTable` ?

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin edit your POST, not the answer, ok ?

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin no, I rejected it, you need to add the screen-shot to your post, not my answer

Comment: sorry @Shai Rado